# SQL Server Password got reverted to the old one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, passwords, trace

Today I tried to login into our SQL server via SSMS and found that the login did not work. I found that somehow the old password worked but not the new one. I do not know how this happened. I have changed this password months ago and has been working flawlessly. Usually

- I am the only one who changes password and creates new ones.
- No one else has access to the DB (AFAIK)

I am clueless how this happened. We do have a couple of new IT people, some of whom have access to the DB using this login. They had the *old* password which was stored in the application.

1. Is it possible that they can attempt login via old password and the database automatically recognizes it and changes the password to the old one?
2. Is there any way I can trace password change in the error log.

I have run `EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0` but it is was not of much help but I can see the failed logins. At this point we are logging only failed logins, not all logins. Is there a better way to trace how this password got changed?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're attempting to access the same server using the same and auth type and username? As far as I know, SQL Server will never randomly change the password for you.

Comment: Absolutely. Tried this from RDP as well + remote SSMS. Both fails with new password. Works with old password. We have only one instance of server running.

Comment: Is Enforce Password Policy enabled?

Comment: For this user, No. I did create another user today and disabled enforce policy password for the new user but never touched this user.

Answer (score 0):

I did some checking and found others having this same problem.

If you create a new login name, you can use this to prevent it from happening:

```
CREATE LOGIN loginName WITH PASSWORD = '<enterStrongPasswordHere>', 
CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
```

This will ensure that Enforce Password Policy is not enabled.

Comment: I am still not entirely user though. Our new IT person says he used that old password for 2 days and it worked. I had this problem *only today* after I created a new user I guess. There is still grey area.

Comment: Is it possible that your server has been compromised?

Comment: No it can not be accessed from outside. The data is otherwise fine. The only thing is we have new people accessing it.

Comment: Another interesting this is if my creating of new account causes this unexpected behavior, it did not reset other logins password. The other work OK, Only the main login was affected. And we know someone was using main login to access db.

Comment: The only other things I can think of, besides my answer, is to make sure that no code is playing with the password, and monitor the activity using PROFILER for SA activities. Watch closely for all the transactions and checkup the difference.